# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

i take runtime error at the title. i searched on google but i couldn't find about 'on' property.
 I m trying to do if grid one not selected, when clicking create button of second grid, give an alert and close pop up edit.

**My Grid**

```
               @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kurslar.Models.DonemKursSinifi>()
    .Name("sinifGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Tanim).Width(50).Title("Tanim");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DersAdi).Width(50).Title("Ders");
        columns.Bound(p => p.EgitmenAdiSoyadi).Width(50).Title("Eğitmen");
        columns.Bound(p => p.KontenjanSayisi).Width(50).Title("Kontenjan");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DonemBaslangicBitis).Width(50).Title("Dönem");
        columns.Bound(p => p.TarifeId).Width(50).Title("Tarife");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DonemId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DersId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.EgitmenId).Visible(false);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Güncelle"); command.Destroy().Text("Sil"); }).Width(180);

    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                      .Window(conf => conf.Title("Yeni Sınıf"))
                        .TemplateName("DonemKursSinifiTemplate"))
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Sınıf Ekle"))
    .Events(e => e.Edit("onEditSinif"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GridDonemKursSinifi", "Tanim").Data("data"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("DonemKursSinifiOlustur", "Tanim").Data("dataCreate"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("DonemKursSinifiGuncelle", "Tanim").Data("dataUpdate"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DonemKursSinifiSil", "Tanim"))
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
     )
     .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

)
```

**And this is javascript part which give error**

```
alert("You must firstly select a row from grid one.");
var grid = $("#sinifGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.cancelRow();
```

Comment: is there anybody to know what is 'on' property?